# Use VBA to import data from SSMS joined table into an Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ssms

I am trying to import some fields from two tables that need to be joined from SSMS. The importation process is through VBA. When importing from a singular table, my query ran fine but when I tried introducing a joined format, I received the error **Run-time error -2147217900 (80040e14) Incorrect Syntax near 'dd'** This piece of code is where the error gets thrown:
**'The line item below is what gets highlighted and throws the error message
rsData.Open strQuery, objConn**

```
 Sub GetData_Using_VERSION_ID()
 Dim strConnectionString As String, strQuery As String, strMessage As String
 Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset
 
 Dim varArrayReader As Variant
 Dim tot_rows As Long
 Dim intLBoundColumn As Long, intUBoundColumn As Long ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 1st dimension of the Array (columns)
 Dim intLBoundRow As Long, intUBoundRow As Long  ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 2nd dimension of the Array (rows)
 Dim intLBoundColumn2 As Long, intUBoundColumn2 As Long ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 1st dimension of the Array (columns)
 Dim intLBoundRow2 As Long, intUBoundRow2 As Long  ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 2nd dimension of the Array (rows)
 Dim intLBoundColumn3 As Long, intUBoundColumn3 As Long ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 1st dimension of the Array (columns)
 Dim intLBoundRow3 As Long, intUBoundRow3 As Long  ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 2nd dimension of the Array (rows)
 Dim intLBoundColumn4 As Long, intUBoundColumn4 As Long ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 1st dimension of the Array (columns)
 Dim intLBoundRow4 As Long, intUBoundRow4 As Long  ' this variable is meant to hold the lower and upper indexes of the 2nd dimension of the Array (rows)
 
 
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Dim found As Integer
 Dim VId As String
 Dim ews As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim sws As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim lws As Excel.Worksheet
 
  'Variable to determine if App version is found for ny_id lookup
 found = 0
 
 VId = Cells(1, 3)
 
 Set ews = Worksheets("Employer_Data")
 Set sws = Worksheets("Student_Data")
 Set lws = Worksheets("Loan_Data")
 
 
 'Determine if Ny_id has been found or not to set the initial total rows
 'tot_rows is the starting point for the inserting of the headers and data beneath them
 If Cells(2, 1) = "" Or Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
    tot_rows = 3
 Else
    tot_rows = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 3
 End If
 
 'See if valid app version id input for lookup
 If VId = "" Or Not IsNumeric(VId) Then
    Rows(tot_rows - 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    ews.Rows(tot_rows - 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    sws.Rows(tot_rows - 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    lws.Rows(tot_rows - 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Cells(tot_rows - 1, 1).Value = "Bad Application_Version_ID Entered"
    ews.Cells(tot_rows - 1, 1).Value = "No Application_Version_ID Entered"
    sws.Cells(tot_rows - 1, 1).Value = "No Application_Version_ID Entered"
    lws.Cells(tot_rows - 1, 1).Value = "No Application_Version_ID Entered"
 Else
 
 'Connection string for our Dev Database
 strConnectionString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB;" _
                & "Data Source=NAME REMOVED FOR DATA INTEGRITY;" _
                & "Initial Catalog=NAME REMOVED FOR DATA INTEGRITY;" _
                & "User ID=NAME REMOVED FOR DATA INTEGRITY;" _
                & "Password=NAME REMOVED FOR DATA INTEGRITY;"
'***THIS CODE WORKS BY PULLING FIELDS FROM A SINGULAR TABLE SOURCE BUT I NEED TO PULL FIELDS FROM A JOINED TABLE
'Add/Update/Remove Fields Here
'NY_CALCULATION SQL Statement to pull data
'        strQuery = ""
'    strQuery = strQuery & "SELECT NY_ID, APPLICATION_VERSION_ID, grad_year, year, month, calc_year, marital_status, number_dependents, " _
'    & "annual_gross_salary , qual_income, month_part_cont, monthly_payment_non_law, monthly_payment_law, month_lrap_benefit, spouse_annual_gross_salary, " _
'    & "spouse_monthly_payment_ug , orig_principle_law, adjusted_orig_principle_law " _
'    & "FROM  [dbo].[NY_CALCULATION]" & " WHERE APPLICATION_VERSION_ID in (" & VId & ") order by application_version_id, month"
'*************************************************************

'THIS IS THE QUERY STRUCTURE THAT I NEED TO USE TO PULL THE NECESSARY FIELDS FROM SSMS INTO AN EXCEL FILE, HOWEVER AS MENTIONED I RECEIVE AN ERROR. I ASSUME THAT MAYBE I DIDN'T STRUCTURE THE QUERY PROPERLY?   
        strQuery = ""
    strQuery = strQuery & "SELECT ah.NY_ID, ah.NEW_APPLICATION_ID, dd.GRAD_YEAR, dd.FIRST_NAME, dd.LAST_NAME, dd.MARITAL_STATUS, dd.NUMBER_DEPENDENTS, " _
    & "dd.LRAP_PROGRAM, dd.CREATED_TIME " _
    & "FROM  [dbo].[NY_APPLICATION_HISTORY] ah" _
    & "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[NY_DEMOGRAPHIC_DATA] dd" _
    & "ON dd.APPLICATION_VERSION_ID = ah.NEW_APPLICATION_ID" _
    & " WHERE APPLICATION_VERSION_ID in (" & VId & ")" _
    & "ORDER BY ah.NEW_APPLICATION_ID"
   
    'Execute SQL statement
    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
    objConn.Open strConnectionString
    Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
    'The line item below is what gets highlighted and throws the error message
    rsData.Open strQuery, objConn
    
     'Check to see if we were able to find data with select statement
     If rsData.EOF Then
        Cells(tot_rows - 1, 2).Value = "No Calculation Data found for that Application_Version_ID"
    Else
```

Comment: You need a space after `dd` and `ah` and your final `)`

Comment: No worries.  A simple way to diagnose these is to debug the end result, so `debug.? strQuery` and then take it into SSMS